# Run powershell through Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am an early Exchange Server admin and would like to start using Task Scheduler to call Powershell Scripts which are located in my C:\ drive.

I would like help to run the following Powershell Script named `Script A` located in `C:\Scripts\Script A Folder\Script A.PS1`

I will also need the parameter `-Reportonly` appended to the end of the shell script. I am currently using the following:

Program / Script

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Add Arguments

```
-version 2.0 -noexit -command ". 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer -auto; - File "C:\Scripts\TScript A Folder\Script A.ps1"
```

Would I need to run a Batch file or can this work without?

I cannot get it to work for love nor money. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you get script A to work when calling direct from powershell / cmd? That's what you need to do. When you have that working, put it in Task Scheduler and make sure it gets run by an appropriate user

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to mix `-Command` and `-File` with PowerShell. If it does work I don't know which one will execute first. Roll at that up into Script A.ps1 and call it from there.

Comment: The parameter for your `-Command` argument is missing a closing double quote.  What exactly are you expecting `- File "C:\Scripts\TScript A Folder\Script A.ps1"` to do?  You understand you've got it embedded in your `-Command` argument, right?  Did you mean `&'C:\Scripts\TScript A Folder\Script A.ps1'`?

Comment: `- file` should not have a space either missed the comment window and it does not make sense to have the ; before it. Use arco's comment. Test it locally. You will get these errors to help you debug

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted the powershell the execution policy in order to allow ps scripts? If not you have to do the following:

1. start CMD
2. type powershell
3. type Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
4. press ENTER

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to run a PowerShell script straight from the **Actions** tab in the **Task Scheduler**.

This is what I have on my server:
[image: Screenshot of Task Scheduler]

What I have is:

1. Start a program: powershell
2. Add arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "S:\Prod\Permission matrix\Permission matrix.ps1" -ProcessNow "Process now"`

In your case that would be for **Add arguments**:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\Script A Folder\Script A.PS1" -Reportonly
```

If you have more switches and parameters, you may simplify it by using a 'caller script' that contains these. So in your Scheduled Task you do this:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\Caller.PS1"
```

And in the 'Caller.PS1' you can have something like this:

```
&'C:\Scripts\My script' -Switch -OptionA 'Amazing' -OptionB 'Great'
```

This way you don't need to cram it all together in that small little box called 'Add arguments' in the Task Scheduler.